# ColdFusion entityLoad filter criteria generating java error

Tags: java, apache, orm, coldfusion, catalina

I have an orm application that works perfectly fine on the development server. When bringing the code to the production environment, rebuilding tables and attempting to visit a page with entityLoad that has filter criteria i get a blank page with no error. Upon looking in the logs the real error appears.

here is a sample of the code attempting to execute

```
<cfset agenda2 = entityLoad('agenda2', { title = 'third' })>
```

and here is the error returned

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [CfmServlet] in context with path [/] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions.eq(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/hibernate/criterion/Criterion;
    at coldfusion.orm.hibernate.CriteriaBuilder.addField(CriteriaBuilder.java:71)
    at coldfusion.orm.hibernate.CriteriaBuilder.addFields(CriteriaBuilder.java:57)
    at coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernatePersistenceManager.load(HibernatePersistenceManager.java:382)
    at coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernatePersistenceManager.load(HibernatePersistenceManager.java:333)
    at coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernatePersistenceManager.load(HibernatePersistenceManager.java:303)
    at coldfusion.orm.ORMUtils.entityLoad(ORMUtils.java:100)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.EntityLoad(CFPage.java:9417)
    at cfagenda22ecfm597466656.runPage(agenda2.cfm:1)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:246)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.handlePageInvoke(IncludeTag.java:736)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:572)
    at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
    at coldfusion.filter.IpFilter.invoke(IpFilter.java:45)
    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:466)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:141)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:78)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:58)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at coldfusion.inspect.weinre.MobileDeviceDomInspectionFilter.doFilter(MobileDeviceDomInspectionFilter.java:121)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:422)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am assuming this is something related to bad server configuration but im not entirely sure how to gage the situation. any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ended up applying hotfix 5 for coldfusion 11 and this resolved the issue. the hotfix details don't describe entityload as having an issue however they do describe a number of issues any of which could have been the cause of our issue.

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/bugs-fixed-in-coldfusion-11-update-5.html

Hope this helps anyone else who may run into a similar issue